# select-option angular, php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I want to show data from database in the select-option (drop down) in my form

This is HTML code

```
<select ng-init="get_position()" class="form-control">
        <option ng-repeat="position in positionItems" value="">{{position.position_name}}</option>
</select>
```

This is controller (Angular)

```
$scope.get_position = function () {
    $http.get("/pooh/action.php?action=get_position").success(function (data) {
        $scope.positionItems = data;
        console.log("GET POSITION!!!");
    });
}
```

and this is PHP

```
/**  Function to Get Staff Position  **/

function get_position() {    
    $qry = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `position`');
    $data = array();
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
        $data[] = array(
            "position_name" => $rows['name']
        );
    }
    print_r(json_encode($data));
    return json_encode($data);  
}
```

I understand that the mistake might be from the html code. How to binds controller to form in angular syntax?

Comment: Where is the problem statement.

Comment: Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

Comment: are you getting data back from your php function? EDIT: I mean from your get request in angular

Comment: Try this: ng-repeat="position in positionItems track by $index"

Comment: I just noticed that I add console.log($scope.positionItems);
it occur ReferenceError in my console

Comment: I can fix it. Thank You all.
ng-repeat="position in positionItems track by $index" help me a lot 
Thank You VVK

Answer (score 0):

`?action=get_position` will not call your php function unless you have some logic in your script to grab the `$_GET` variable, and even then, you still need to call your function.

Remove that, and call your function in the php script.

```
function get_position() {    
    $qry = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `position`');
    $data = array();
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $data[] = array(
                    "position_name" => $rows['name']
                    );
    }
    print_r(json_encode($data));
    return json_encode($data);  
}

// call your function
get_position();
```